# Multiple record increase by one

Tags: ms-access-2010

I have this code to access:

```
Option Compare Database

Public Sub batchAdd(records As Integer)

    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
    Dim i As Integer

    Set db = CurrentDb
    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("tblMeters")

    i = 1

    Do While i <= records

        rs.AddNew
        rs!value1 = Me.value1
        rs!Ticket = Me.Ticket
        rs!value2 = Me.value2
        rs!value3 = Me.value3
        rs!value4 = Me.value4
        rs!value5 = Me.value5
        rs!value6 = Me.value6
        rs!value7 = Me.value7
        rs.Update

        i = i + 1

    Loop

    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    Set db = Nothing

End Sub

Private Sub cmdAddRecords_Click()

    batchAdd Me.txtRecords
    Me.tblMeters_sub.Requery

End Sub
```

My question was how to increase the ticket value of +1 for each record inserted.

Example: If I insert the ticket with a value of 1 to 10 times, the first time will be 1 and the second 2, then 3 .... how do I change this code for the ticket value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adjust this line to:

```
rs!Ticket = i
```